# onclick not working on dynamic ids using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wrote a dropdown which will have a dynamic id. That means on click of 'add' the dropdown will be added and have an id like `option-1`, `option-2`. I tried using an `onclick` action on these dynamic ids but it's not working.

I need the `onclick` action based on `id` but not `class`. Please help me achieve that.

```js
let Index = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  add();
  $("#Email-${Index}").click(function() {
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
  });
});


function add() {
  $("#list-container").append(
    `<div class="form-group" style="display: flex">
      <select class="drop form-control" name="email" id="option-${Index}">
        <option value="volvo">choose</option>
      </select>
    </div>`
  );
  Index++;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" defer />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Share</h3>
          <div id="list-container" class=""></div>
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; margin-right: 50px;" onclick="add()"></i>
        </div>
```

Comment: There's a few issues here. Firstly you need to use the backtick character to delimit your interpolated string. Secondly there's no `#Email-N` element in the DOM. Lastly, you'll need to use a delegated event handler as presumably the element in the click event is dynamically added to the page somewhere. In addition, why can't you use classes? It's **by far** the best way of doing what you need.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I dont understand can you explain on click of select element based on id I should get alert couls you please help me

Comment: Well firstly can you explain what element you're trying to select as `#Email-1` doesn't exist.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  not #Email-1 its #option-1 
forex onload I had an dropdown id is option-1 on click the alert should come 
if I click add and click on the dropdown added id is option-2 the alert should come 
like that I am trying

Comment: `$("#Email-${Index}").click(function() {` < your code. I assume that's a typo then and it's supposed to be `#option-1`?

Comment: yes not only option-1 it should work for option-2 option-3 and so on @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Ok, and can you clarify why you can't use a class? It's by far the best practice in this situation

Comment: No, actually I had work on that if I use class it will duplicate but id will be unique so I need that please help me ! @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: But the whole point ***is*** to duplicate the class. That's why it's better practice

Comment: actually I want to use id @RoryMcCrossan please say me

Comment: @madhu Sorry i will not able to help you. i have deleted my 100% working answer. As far as i know. You will not be able achieve what you are trying to with dynamically added elements  having that many limitations of using this  `' '` OR `" "` in your code in these modern coding days. You have limitation of not using class you have limited of not using `" "` i am not sure what else. I hope someone can help you. Also please edit your question to add all this information

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Index = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  add();
  $("#Email-${Index}").click(function() {
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
  });
});


function add() {
  $("#list_container").append(
    `<select class="form-control" name="email" style="display:flex;margin:1rem 0;" id="option-${Index}">
      <option value="volvo">choose</option>
    </select>`
  );
  Index++;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" defer />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Share</h3>
          <div id="list_container">

          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; margin-right: 50px;" onclick="add()"></i>
        </div>
```